# How to combine Swing and SpringFramework?

Tags: java, spring, swing, event-dispatch-thread

Swing requires to run from within Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). How to ensure this in Spring context?

In some tutorials, [like this one](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-springswing/j-springswing.html), swing components are just instantiated like normal beans. Is this ok?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22864008/how-to-configure-spring-boot-with-swing-application

Answer (score 1):

As you have already guessed, it would be safer to run your *Swing* code within the *Event Dispatching Thread* aka **EDT** because most of the Swing components are not thread safe. Here is what stated in Oracle docs:

> Swing event handling code runs on a special thread known as the event
>   dispatch thread. Most code that invokes Swing methods also runs on
>   this thread. This is necessary because most Swing object methods are
>   not "thread safe": invoking them from multiple threads risks thread
>   interference or memory consistency errors.

So you should be safe to go if your initialiaze your *Spring* `ApplicationContext` whithin the EDT thread so that your components get initialized and run in the same thread:

```java
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
{
  public void run() 
  {
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext( "your-application-context.xml" ); // pay attention to context so that it is not left open
  }
});
```

Comment: not this is not good idea, EDT waitng until whatever from ClassPathXmlApplicationContext is loaded, invokeLater is designated to notify methods implemented in Swing APIs, methods in those APIs,

Comment: That may be a shortcut yes and not an ultimate solution.